# overflow is sending dropdown behind the parent div, z-index is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

folks,
I can't seem to figure out why overflow is breaking the code

so below code works fine in two conditions.
a) if I remove overflow-x and overflow-y from .bs-exmple
or
b) if I remove ul and li

but I need both in my code, however with these css and ul and li being in code, the dropdown collapses behind the div. what am i missing

```css
.bs-example {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.bs-example .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="list-group ">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Menu
                </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

so you see, the image below shows the dropdown behind the div

[image: result]

Comment: Provide codepen or jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: @SagarKharche No, the built-in _Stack snippet_ is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdownMenuButton").click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.helper {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.bs-example{
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;  
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="helper">

    <div class="bs-example">
      <ul class="list-group ">
        <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

   <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Menu
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ehsan, thanks for the response, but your code is basically taking the dropdown out of li element, In my code although there is only one li list item, but there will be multiple li items within list-group and each li will have its own dropdown, so its important to keep the dropdrown within li. This is exactaly what I am hustling with. if i move the dropdown outside of li or if i remove ul li, everything works.